# Cannot get spark/pyspark working on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark, installation

Have a new MacBook w/ macOS Mojave but cannot get spark/pyspark working. I have done the following:

- Downloaded the latest Apache Spark from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
- Unzipped it in my home directory (`/Users/myname/`)
- Renamed the folder `spark`
- Checked in the Finder window that spark was there, and the folder contained python, bin, and bin/spark-shell subfolders
- Got the ability to pip install packages with: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` >> `python get-pip.py` in the terminal >> Checked that it was installed by doing `import pip` in the python shell >> `sudo easy_install pip` in the regular terminal
- `pip install pyspark`, which worked
- Created both a .bashrc and .bash_profile files in the `Users/myname/` path
- I tried the following versions of the commands in these bash files:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/Users/myname/spark/python"
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/myname/spark/python
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/myname/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

```
export SPARK_HOME=~/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Different installation articles say I should just be able to do `pyspark` in the terminal, or `spark/bin/spark-shell` or just 'bin/spark-shell`, I just keep getting versions of the message

`-bash: pyspark: command not found`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed pyspark from pip, you don't need the standalone installation. You just need to fix you env vars. First, find the location of your site packages:

```
python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

This is probably something like this `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`

Then, add the exports to your bash profile and source it.

```
echo "export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/pyspark" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```